# Azure RM Template. Multiple VMs with multiple data disks

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create a template that will deploy Multiple VMs with variable ammount of multiple data disks by using copy function. I'm following documentation precisely, but my deployment still fails. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#create-multiple-instances-when-copy-wont-work
Please, help me fix this.
azuredeploy.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "dnsLabelPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "windowsOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
      "allowedValues": [
        "2008-R2-SP1",
        "2012-Datacenter",
        "2012-R2-Datacenter"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Windows version. Allowed values: 2008-R2-SP1, 2012-Datacenter, 2012-R2-Datacenter."
      }
    },
    "numDataDisks": {
      "type": "int",
      "maxValue": 64,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "This parameter allows the user to select the number of disks they want"
      }
    },
    "numberOfInstances": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 2,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Number of VMs to deploy"
      }
    },
    "numberOfDataDisksPerVM": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [ 1, 2 ]
    },
      "_artifactsLocation": {
          "type": "string"
      },
      "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
          "type": "securestring"
      }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'dynamicdisk')]",
    "sizeOfDataDisksInGB": 100,
    "diskCaching": "ReadWrite",
    "imagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "imageOffer": "WindowsServer",
    "OSDiskName": "osdiskforwindowssimple",
    "nicName": "dynamicDisksVMNic",
    "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "subnetName": "Subnet",
    "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
    "publicIPAddressName": "dynamicDisksPublicIP",
    "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
    "vmStorageAccountContainerName": "vhds",
    "vmName": "dynamicDisksVM",
    "vmSize": "Standard_DS4",
    "virtualNetworkName": "dynamicDisksVNET",
    "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',variables('subnetName'))]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "diskArray": [
      {
        "name": "datadisk1",
        "lun": 0,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk1.vhd')]"
        },
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "[variables('diskCaching')]",
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDataDisksInGB')]"
      },
      {
        "name": "datadisk2",
        "lun": 1,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk2.vhd')]"
        },
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "[variables('diskCaching')]",
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDataDisksInGB')]"
      },
      {
        "name": "datadisk3",
        "lun": 2,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk3.vhd')]"
        },
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "[variables('diskCaching')]",
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDataDisksInGB')]"
      },
      {
        "name": "datadisk4",
        "lun": 3,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk4.vhd')]"
        },
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "[variables('diskCaching')]",
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDataDisksInGB')]"
      },
    ],
      "nested-TemplateFolder": "nestedtemplates",
      "nested-TemplateFileName": "nested-.json",
      "nested-TemplateParametersFileName": "nested-.parameters.json"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
              },
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[concat('myvm', copyIndex())]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfInstances')]"
      },
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[variables('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[variables('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "osdisk",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/',variables('vmStorageAccountContainerName'),'/',variables('OSDiskName'),'.vhd')]"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          },
          "dataDisks": "[reference(concat('nested-', copyIndex())).outputs.result.value]"
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": "true",
            "storageUri": "[concat('http://',variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat('nested-', copyIndex())]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "copy": {
        "name": "deploycopy",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfInstances')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('nested-TemplateFolder'), '/', variables('nested-TemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parametersLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('nested-TemplateFolder'), '/', variables('nested-TemplateParametersFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "vmName": { "value": "[concat('myvm', copyIndex())]" },
          "storageAccountName": { "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]" },
          "numDataDisks": { "value": "[parameters('numberOfDataDisksPerVM')[copyIndex()]]" }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

nested-.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "numDataDisks": {
      "type": "int",
      "maxValue": 16,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "This parameter allows the user to select the number of disks they want"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "diskArray": [
      {
        "name": "datadisk1",
        "lun": 0,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk1.vhd')]"
        },
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "[variables('diskCaching')]",
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDataDisksInGB')]"
      },
      {
        "name": "datadisk2",
        "lun": 1,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk2.vhd')]"
        },
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "[variables('diskCaching')]",
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDataDisksInGB')]"
      },
      {
        "name": "datadisk3",
        "lun": 2,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk3.vhd')]"
        },
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "[variables('diskCaching')]",
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDataDisksInGB')]"
      },
      {
        "name": "datadisk4",
        "lun": 3,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk4.vhd')]"
        },
        "createOption": "Empty",
        "caching": "[variables('diskCaching')]",
        "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sizeOfDataDisksInGB')]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "result": {
      "type": "array",
      "value": "[take(variables('diskArray'),parameters('numDataDisks'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>So, the asker want's to have dynamic amount of disks with several vm's, so I had to use the nested template approach. For some reason formating breaks if I paste it here, so:</strike>

https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/ml-vm-ml-dd.json

this whole thing doesn't make sense now. You should use the properties copy now:
https://github.com/rjmax/Build2017/blob/master/Act1.TemplateEnhancements/Chapter02.PropertyCopies.json

Comment: Your approach is better! Thank you! I wish there wasn't such an overly complicated example in the Azure documentation when there is much better solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#create-multiple-instances-when-copy-wont-work

Comment: Update: I've marked this as a solution prematurely (sorry). I would like to specify interactively in parameters how many additional disks this template would have, and not change template resources each time I want more or less data disks.

Comment: That what I was trying to do too, but that doesn't work. myvm0 and myvm1 are trying to use the same Data Disk name/URI
https://ghostbin.com/paste/bok5t

Comment: this is amazing! Thank you a lot for showing how it's done!

Comment: @4c74356b41 the link to your template example is broken.

Comment: @woter324 doesn't make sense to use that anymore check updated answer

Comment: Thanks. Now, to work out how to create X no. datadisks of size Y and X no. datadisks of size Z, where X, Y & Z are all provided as parameters at deployment-time...

Comment: create a question, we can help @woter324